# Having issues with reaction role command... Node.js, Discord.js, Javascript

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Hello I have been having an issue with creating a reaction role command in Discord.js I do not understand why it is a typeerror and any help will be greatly appreciated. I have no clue how to fix this and I have been trying for ages please explain I have NO CLUE what went wrong...............

Thank you

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'reactionrole',
    description: 'Creates a reaction role for games',
    async execute(prefix, message, args, client) {
        await message.delete().catch(O_o => { });

        const minecraft = message.guild.roles.get('823987141239504929'); // Minecraft Role
        const Fortnite = message.guild.roles.get('823987679078121543'); // Fortnite
        const Hitman = message.guild.roles.get('824007858953388032'); // Hitman
        const AmongUs = message.guild.roles.get('823987894569664522'); // Among Us
        const RocketLeague = message.guild.roles.get('823988431402434580'); // Rocket League
        const FNAF = message.guild.roles.get('823988527673901126'); // FNAF
        const NightGaurdSimulator = message.guild.roles.get('823988658440765460'); // Night Gaurd Simulator 

        const filter = (reaction, user) => ['️', '', '️', '️', '⚽', '', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;

        const embed = new RichEmbed()
            .setTitle('Avaiilable Roles')
            .setDescription(`
                
            ️ ${minecraft.toString()}
             ${Fortnite.toString()}
            ️ ${Hitman.toString()}
            ️ ${AmongUs.toString()}
            ⚽ ${RocketLeague.toString()}
             ${FNAF.toString()}
             ${NightGaurdSimulator.toString()}
                `)
            .setColor(0xdd9323)
            .setFooter(`ID: ${message.author.id}`);

        message.channel.send(embed).then(async msg => {

            await message.react('️');
            await message.react('');
            await message.react('️');
            await message.react('️');
            await message.react('⚽');
            await message.react('');
            await message.react('');

            message.awaitReactions(filter, {
                max: 1,
                time: 30000,
                errors: ['time']
            }).then(collected => {

                const reaction = collected.first();

                switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
                    case '️':
                        if (message.member.roles.has(a.id)) {
                            msg.delete(2000);
                            return message.channel.send('You are already in this role!').then(m => m.delete(3000));
                        }
                        message.member.addRole(a).catch(err => {
                            console.log(err);
                            return message.channel.send(`Error adding you to this role: **${err.message}**.`);
                        });
                        message.channel.send(`You have been added to the **${minecraft.name}** role!`).then(m => m.delete(3000));
                        msg.delete();
                        break;
                    case '':
                        if (message.member.roles.has(b.id)) {
                            msg.delete(2000);
                            return message.channel.send('You are already in this role!').then(m => m.delete(3000));
                        }
                        message.member.addRole(b).catch(err => {
                            console.log(err);
                            return message.channel.send(`Error adding you to this role: **${err.message}**.`);
                        });
                        message.channel.send(`You have been added to the **${Fortnite.name}** role!`).then(m => m.delete(3000));
                        msg.delete();
                        break;
                    case '️':
                        if (message.member.roles.has(c.id)) {
                            msg.delete(2000);
                            return message.channel.send('You are already in this role!').then(m => m.delete(3000));
                        }
                        message.member.addRole(c).catch(err => {
                            console.log(err);
                            return message.channel.send(`Error adding you to this role: **${err.message}**.`);
                        });
                        message.channel.send(`You have been added to the **${Hitman.name}** role!`).then(m => m.delete(3000));
                        msg.delete();
                        break;
                        case '️':
                            if (message.member.roles.has(c.id)) {
                                msg.delete(2000);
                                return message.channel.send('You are already in this role!').then(m => m.delete(3000));
                            }
                            message.member.addRole(c).catch(err => {
                                console.log(err);
                                return message.channel.send(`Error adding you to this role: **${err.message}**.`);
                            });
                            message.channel.send(`You have been added to the **${AmongUs.name}** role!`).then(m => m.delete(3000));
                            msg.delete();
                            break;
                            case '⚽':
                                if (message.member.roles.has(c.id)) {
                                    msg.delete(2000);
                                    return message.channel.send('You are already in this role!').then(m => m.delete(3000));
                                }
                                message.member.addRole(c).catch(err => {
                                    console.log(err);
                                    return message.channel.send(`Error adding you to this role: **${err.message}**.`);
                                });
                                message.channel.send(`You have been added to the **${RocketLeague.name}** role!`).then(m => m.delete(3000));
                                msg.delete();
                                break;
                                case '':
                                    if (message.member.roles.has(c.id)) {
                                        msg.delete(2000);
                                        return message.channel.send('You are already in this role!').then(m => m.delete(3000));
                                    }
                                    message.member.addRole(c).catch(err => {
                                        console.log(err);
                                        return message.channel.send(`Error adding you to this role: **${err.message}**.`);
                                    });
                                    message.channel.send(`You have been added to the **${FNAF.name}** role!`).then(m => m.delete(3000));
                                    msg.delete();
                                    break;
                                    case '':
                                        if (message.member.roles.has(c.id)) {
                                            msg.delete(2000);
                                            return message.channel.send('You are already in this role!').then(m => m.delete(3000));
                                        }
                                        message.member.addRole(c).catch(err => {
                                            console.log(err);
                                            return message.channel.send(`Error adding you to this role: **${err.message}**.`);
                                        });
                                        message.channel.send(`You have been added to the **${NightGaurdSimulator.name}** role!`).then(m => m.delete(3000));
                                        msg.delete();
                                        break;
                }
            }).catch(collected => {
                return message.channel.send(`I couldn't add you to this role!`);
            });

        });

        exports.help = {
            name: 'roles'
        };

    }
}

Console error:

(node:38165) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.guild.roles.get is not a function
```

Comment: Your code is in V11. Are you sure it's supposed to be this way? For your error: `message.guild.roles.cache.get` - You forgot `cache`. But there's also `addRole()` which no longer exists in V12.

Comment: uh oh do you think there is a better way to make a reaction role command then

Comment: And where is the type error? You should include this in your question

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a few issues with this, you're using `message.awaitReactions` which would result in putting a time so it wouldn't be permanent. I suggest you do this in the event `Client#messageReactionAdd` if anything. Also I noticed you have `member.roles.has()`, in v12, you need the cache before any collection methods (such as has) and to add a role it'd be `member.roles.add()`. If you need more v11 -> v12, check out discord.js' guide:
https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#before-you-start